# How to invalidate whole cache for Apollo GraphQL (not for one specific query) onclick

Tags: javascript, caching, graphql, apollo, invalidation

What I need is to force all the queries that I have on pages to refetch data after clicking one button.

I have found the soultion for one specific query here (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/), but it's not clear have can I do this for all the queries at one time.

Comment: I think a couple more details are in order here. Firstly, what is it you're trying to accomplish with this button? (Just making everything reload?) Invalidating the cache might not be the best solution, we've found that messing with the cache often has cascading and annoying effects. What you could do, is compile some sort of master refetchQuery. Secondly, could you show relevant code to this issue and what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @Sterling Archer Basicaly what I need is to refetch all the queries at one time by clicking the button (not whole page, but only the queries). And I dont want to mess with every single query and refetch it. I have no code for that just because I haven't found how to deal with it. Thats why I'm here.

Comment: "*I need to force all the queries that I have on pages to refetch data*" - why would you need that? Why would *all* the data on the page change? What data do you have stored in the cache that you want to get rid of?

Comment: @Bergi I need that because I'm writing reporting system with a lot of data and charts and some times user may want to update all the queries with the same parametres just to udate the data.

Comment: In that case, [refetching the queries using `client.refetchQueries({include:"all"})`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/refetching/) might be easier and more appropriate than invalidating the cache, although both are an option.

Answer (score 0):

Right on that page you have already linked, there's https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#resetting-the-cache

> ### Resetting the cache
>
> Sometimes, you might want to reset the cache entirely, such as when a
> user logs out. To accomplish this, call `client.resetStore`. This method
> is asynchronous, because it also refetches any of your active queries.
>
> ```
> import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
> function Profile() {
>     const { data, client } = useQuery(PROFILE_QUERY);
>     return (
>       <Fragment>
>         <p>Current user: {data?.currentUser}</p>
>         <button onClick={async ()=>client.resetStore()}>
>             Log out
>         </button>
>       </Fragment>
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> > To reset the cache without refetching active queries, use
> > `client.clearStore()` instead of `client.resetStore()`.